# Android app to view and measure dimensions of STL?

Tags: 3d-models, software

I have received an STL file from a designer.

This file can be 3D printed after slicing.

However, I am far from home and from the printer so currently it is impossible to print this model.

I wish though measure some dimensions for correctness.

Another fact: I don't have access to Windows computer, only an Android based tablet.

So a very similar question to [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/tool-to-measure-in-stl-files?newreg=1d91099056dd45f2a438ebaa1ce2c8f7):

Which Android tool is able to present (i.e. view), AND measure dimensions in an STL?

Preferably without strong network connection requirement (i.e. not browser-based)

Comment: Hello Daniel, IMHO this is a recommendation question and as such these questions might be closed by the community as such questions are not allowed on SE web sites, please see our [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) overview.

Comment: Where should I post this then? Please advise :) Thank you